# jquery strip href path (but keep hash value)

Tags: jquery, hash

I'm updating this super old medical site and trying to figure out a way to deal with hundreds of hrefs that each have a document plus a #hash-value, like so...

```
<a href="mind.html#cretinism" target="_top">CRETINISM</a>
<a href="brain.html#delirium" target="_top">DELIRIUM</a>
<a href="body-mind.html#dementia" target="_top">DEMENTIA</a>
<a href="body.html#emotions" target="_top">EMOTIONS</a>
<a href="chem.html#fears" target="_top">FEARS</a>
```

What I'm trying to do is to keep the hash value, and get rid of the document, see. Thus, what I'd like to end up with would be this:

```
<a href="#cretinism" target="_top">CRETINISM</a>
<a href="#delirium" target="_top">DELIRIUM</a>
<a href="#dementia" target="_top">DEMENTIA</a>
<a href="#emotions" target="_top">EMOTIONS</a>
<a href="#fears" target="_top">FEARS</a>
```

Or, optionally, to make it so that onclick, it ignores the document and just responds to the hash value. As in,

```
// pseudo code, obviously
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('href').sliceOffEveryCharBeforeThe('#');
});
```

Whew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is fairly trivial with jQuery although the best solution would be to adjust at server if at all possible.

```
// loop through all "a" in page  
$('a').attr('href', function(_, oldHref){
    // if it has a hash use that, if not use old href
    return this.hash ? this.hash : oldHref;
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jk68c6xy/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks very much; I've accepted this answer because it seemed simpler than the other, which also worked.

Comment: better to do it in page itself anyway I think...then links can be copied if needed

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var obj = $(this);
  var newvalue = obj.attr('href').replace(/[^#]*/, '');
  obj.attr('href', newvalue);
  $('#result').text(this.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<a href="mind.html#cretinism" target="_top">CRETINISM</a>
<a href="brain.html#delirium" target="_top">DELIRIUM</a>
<a href="body-mind.html#dementia" target="_top">DEMENTIA</a>
<a href="body.html#emotions" target="_top">EMOTIONS</a>
<a href="chem.html#fears" target="_top">FEARS</a>

<p id="result"></p>
```